# Можно ли на локальном сервере (на своём компе) задавать права папке 777?

Tags: php

Можно ли на локальном сервере (на своём компе) задавать права папке 777? Или это можно делать только на хостинге?

Comment: Ну и конечно же Вы это хотите сделать имея локальный сервер на венде? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операционная система Windows не поддерживает права доступа к файлом и папкам POSIX-совместимых операционных систем (GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS X). Но Вы всегда можете добавить права на запись для всех через свойства директории в ОС Windows, это будет некоторым аналогом 777 в Linux.

Comment: Если на локальном сервере установлена POSIX-совместимая ОС -- просто сделайте chmod -R 0777 /путь/к/директории (параметр -R рекурсивно сменит права внутри директории).